# Integrate $\csc(1/z)$ on a contour through $0$

Tags: residue-calculus

$\gamma$ is the (triangle) contour $i\longrightarrow-i\longrightarrow1\longrightarrow i$.
$\def\rmd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}$

Using *Mathematica* to evaluate the directional limit at $0$ on $\gamma$ `Limit[1/Sin[1/z], z -> 0, Direction -> -I]`
I get $0$. [Proof: $z=iy,\lim_{y\to0}\sinh\frac1y=\infty\Rightarrow\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac1{\sinh\frac1y}=0$]
So the integrand is bounded and continuous on $\gamma$, so the integral is finite.

Using *Mathematica* to evaluate the integral `NIntegrate[1/Sin[1/z], {z, I, -I, 1, I}]`

I get
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}=\frac{i\pi }{6}$$
I try to prove this.

Sum of residues at $z=\frac1{\pi n},n=1,2,\dots$
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac1{\frac d{dz}\sin(1/z)|_{z=1/\pi n}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac1{-\frac{\cos(1/z)}{z^2}|_{z=1/\pi n}}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\pi ^2 n^2}=\frac{1}{12}$$
Then
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}\rmd z=2\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{12}=\frac{i\pi }{6}$$
Is this proof correct? I am worried since $f(z)$ has a non-isolated singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: The point $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of $\frac{1}{\sin{(1/z)}}$. It is a limit point of poles because $\frac{1}{n\pi}$ is a pole for each integer $n \neq 0$. Every deleted $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $z=0$ has at least one point of the form $z = \frac{1}{n\pi}$. You cannot express a Laurent series of $\frac{1}{\sin{(1/z)}}$ near $z = 0$.

Comment: @Accelerator Yes. In the last sentence I wrote that "$f(z)$ has a non-isolated singularity at $z=0$", so I am worried about the proof. But in the first part I showed that the integral on contour $\gamma$ is finite.

Comment: Oh, my bad. For some reason, I read your last sentence as "I am worried *if* $f(z)$ has a non-isolated singularity at $z=0$."

Comment: @Accelerator Ok. I will fix the last sentence.

Comment: This is not correct because there is an essential singularity with no local Laurent series expansion at zero, and to skirt around zero... you have to evaluate an error term which you haven't done

Comment: Use residue calculus with an indented contour?

Comment: The contour integral can be evaluated. But the value of the integral has no connection with residue at 0 for the simple reason, residue is defined only for isolated singularities.

Comment: @Accelerator Having the right answer doesn’t mean you had a right method. There is a very genuine problem at zero which needs addressing. Also I invite you to prove the clockwise  indent vanishes: $z\csc z^{-1}$ is not convergent as $z\to0$.

Comment: Though, if the answer really is $\pi i/6$, then this would imply (and be equivalent to): $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{2}(2n+1)\cdot e^{-i\phi}\right)\cdot e^{i\phi}\,\,\mathrm{d}\phi=0$$Which is not obvious to me.